# Calculate package Y used to ship X products

Tags: php, math

We have a predefined set of packaging material available (read: boxes).
We have a set of object that need to be packaged in one of these boxes.

We know the dimensions of each packaging material.
We know the dimensions of each object.
We know no more than one box will be used.

Now the most basic approach would probably be: calculate volume of combined products and take the box that is the closest match to this value (never below though). But this does not take into account the different shapes/dimensions of objects.

So one would also have to add the requirement that the box at the very least can contain the largest object (of all the objects given) dimensions wise.

We're looking at a way of figuring out how we can loop through each product, virtually put it in the box, and then proceed with the space remaining (taking into account an object can fit into this space in various ways).

Comment: Is this homework? Either way, what have you tried so far? Try working it out yourself first and then ask for help with a specific problem.  "Write my app for me" questions are not ideal.

Comment: Just to be clear, you're looking for the minimum volume required for a set of objects with different dimensions, right? Not the minimum volume for a set of replicate objects.

Comment: Which box was used? The one the guy in the warehouse looked at and said "Yea, that looks big enough". If it wasn't then the answer is the 2nd one he tried or the box with the hole in it where you irregular shaped object poked through.

Comment: It is not homework. It's actual work/office. We're theorizing how this could be achieved most ideally. The thing is, when you put product X in package Y, you're left with 3 "boxes" (read: empty spaces) inside the original box which can contain the remaining products. However, since the shape of products varies quite a lot, you cannot always assume the next product will use only one of these "new boxes". Some here argue it is far too complicated and simply cannot be achieved within a reasonable fault tolerance (5% of all predications is allowed to be faulty).

Comment: This is a broad problem in its general form (ie. any form factor). I suggest to start by looking at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bin_packing_problem and then refine your question.

Comment: Hey thanks belisarius! That's a very interesting link you posted there. Going to share it with the rest right away :)

Comment: Just to note that when you put product X in package Y, there are three ways of orienting the product (assuming cuboids) so you have 9 possible empty space possibilities.

Answer (score 2):

You might want to take a look at some literature on the subject. One I might recommend is:

Three-dimensional bin packing problem with variable bin height
by Yong Wua, Wenkai Li,Mark Goh and Robert de Souza
European Journal of Operational Research
Volume 202, Issue 2, 16 April 2010, Pages 347-355

It is basically discussing the packing of boxes into a larger box. It provides some pseudocode which might be helpfull as well.